# MiniCssExtractPlugin не работает

Tags: webpack

Просто webpack не видит его, не понимаю. В консоли мне пишет на строчке с

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    })

Method expression is not of Function type
```

require его подхватывает с подсказкой как бы все ок. В папке node_modules он появляется как и в package.json, но он его не видит, редактор его подсвечивает, у него нельзя вызвать свойства и тд..

Пробовал переустанавливать, не помогло. Пробовал менять режим разработки в конце концов просто копировал кусок кода с доки, все ровно он просто не видит его и все.

```
    {
  "name": "second",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "biuld": "webpack --mode=production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode=development --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development --open firefox"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  }
}


const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './index.js',
        analytics: './analytics.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.css'],
        alias: {
            '@main': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            '@css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css')
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png|jpeg)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: А что выводит, если вывести в консоль сам класс как тип? `console.log(MiniCssExtractPlugin)`? Может это наведет на причину проблемы?

Comment: Он заработал, но редактор все ровно подсвечивает некоторые свойства лоадеров или загрузчиков, он не может их найти. Они работают, но редактор их не видит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Редактор их не видит по причине отсутствия типизации у устанавливаемых библиотек, если быть конкретнее, то файлов *.d.ts